# 6 wires one light

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I'm trying to install a replacement hall light and the box has 3 black, 3 white wires and no apparent ground wire, it is connected to a 3 pole switch. My fixture only has a black, white and a ground, once I disconnected the fixture in the hall the bathroom light went out as well, long story short I forgot how to reconnect it as I got called away for something else.  But there were two black connected to one white , which is rather odd, then two whites that went to one connection on the light and one black to the other if any of that helps.  I am trying to figure out out which two blacks go to that one white and white two whites go to the light.  I blew the fuse several times trying to figure it out and one time the light came on but would not shut off.

Comment: What's a "3 pole switch"? Do you mean a 3-way? If so, it's probably not important.

Comment: The white connected to the black is part of the switch loop feeding the lamp. The white should have been marked with black tape or painted black (this is normal for a switch loop but supposed to be marked). You may need to purchase an inexpensive meter to measure the voltage/ resistances on the wires and we can help but more information will be needed to get things working again.

Comment: @EdBeal, saying "the white should have been marked with black tape or painted black" is a bit misleading. Re-marking a switch loop white is a relatively new code in the scope of things. Anything from the 80's and earlier is not likely to be marked, and was not required to be.

Comment: Logan, are you able to put the splices back the way they were? There was NO reason to take apart all the splices in the box. You only need to worry about the connections to the light fixture.

Answer (score 1):

It's not odd that a white connects to the blacks. That's the feed for a switch loop. The black that's in the cable with that white is probably the fixture's hot supply. Once you have that identified it's pretty simple.

- White from the switch connects to the two blacks that aren't in the same cable as that white
- The other whites get bundled with each other and the fixture white
- Black that pairs with the switch white connects to the fixture black
- Fixture ground gets ignored if there's no ground at the box